# How to assign a value to a instance variable in a super class from main method?

Tags: super

I have a teacher class extending a person class.

```
In person class:
String course;

In Teacher extends person class:
String course;

void display(){
System.out.print(super.course);
}

In main method:
Teacher t1 = new Teacher();

 t1.super.course = "ENG101";
 t1.display;
```

Here, the course variable in the super class is inaccessible. How to access it assign value in it?

I am expecting the course variable from Person class to have the value "ENG101".

Comment: Can you simply remove the `course` field from `Teacher` or is this part of the assignment?

Comment: it is part of the assignment. I want to assign value to the course variable of the person class from main method.

Comment: The question is if you need a shadowed variable. If you remove the second one, it will still be there and actually assignable.